# Insert into statement works in sql query and error in c#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

When I try to insert into my `Partial` table, I get a syntax error which I cannot solve; I tried everything and it works fine in access query but in c# it doesn't.

My code:

```
string strcomm = @"Insert Into Partial values(@c_name,@w_name,@ssn,@Product_name,@Price,
@Amount,@Total,@fir,@buy_date,@discount)";

OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(strcomm, connection);


command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_name", 1 /*pills_grid.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value*/);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@w_name", 1 /*pills_grid.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value*/);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ssn", 1 /*pills_grid.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value*/);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_name", 1 /*pills_grid.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value*/);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", 1 /*pills_grid.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value*/);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", 1/* pills_grid.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value*/);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total", 1 /*pills_grid.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value*/);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fir", 1 /*pills_grid.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value*/);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@buy_date", "2010-1-1" /*pills_grid.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value*/);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@discount", 1 /*pills_grid.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value*/);

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I use 1's as inputs just to try nothing more

It works perfectly in Access and throws this error in C#:

> Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Comment: It would be helpful to post the error message. Also, is every column you are inserting of type `INT`?

Comment: Please explain why it is not working.

Comment: [Stop using `AddWithValue`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: @DanWilson i don't not it gives syntax error in insert into statement but it works perfectly in ms access query

Comment: @DourHighArch Why should a person not use `.AddWithValue`?

Comment: @RyanWilson His comment is a link.

Comment: @RyanWilson: read the blog post that the comment is linking to!

Comment: @DourHighArch i'm using it in 10+ insert,update,select statements and it works this is the only statement that gives error i don't think it's from addwithvalue

Comment: Normally the syntax is `insert into TableName (column1, column2) VALUES (@column1, @column2)`, is it not?

Comment: @LarsTech Just noticed that.

Comment: @Amy not necessary when you know the columns order and types it is okay in my syntax too i'm using it

Comment: @Amy If the columns are in the correct order, the SQL statement could work.

Comment: @marc_s I read it, and I have to say, in his case that may apply, but if using stored procedures with input parameters, not really an issue "This is much less of a concern if you’re calling a stored procedure, because the procedure parameter will have its own type, and that’s what will be checked against the underlying tables."

Comment: @marc_s it's simple query no procedures

Comment: @MostafaIbrahem You *should* stop using `AddWithValue`.  Doing so is not meant to address this particular issue, but to improve the quality of your code overall.  Using that method is generally a bad idea for reasons specified in the link.

Comment: @RyanWilson: the question **isn't** about stored procedures ......

Comment: @marc_s I know, and therefore I said in his case it matters, but just saying don't use `.AddWithValue` is kind of misleading. It is case dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Partial` is a reserved word in Access. You should wrap it in square brackets - `[Partial]`.

Comment: Thank you i kept looking in my parameters for reserved words and missed the table name :]